# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Salesforce's [third moderator election](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: David Reed]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Samuel De Rycke who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5274841676513280/0).

Comment: Congratulations @david reed and thank you for all you do and thank you everyone for awesome work here .

Comment: Looking forward to sharing stewardship of this site with you, as we have for some time now.

Comment: Congrats @DavidReed. Well done and well deserved.

Answer (score 33):

Wow. Thank you, everyone! I am really honored to be chosen by this community. I love being a part of SFSE and the work we do as a group - building up our collective knowledge and craft, and making it available to all.

My first promise as moderator is to go slow. Y'all pretty much know what to expect from me as a contributor, and I'll take care to learn my way through moderation from Adrian, Matt, and the rest of the community.

Thank you for your trust. I'm very excited to help SFSE continue to grow and thrive.

Comment: Congrats David Reed. Your dedication to SFSE is commendable

Comment: Congratulations David. What a day! Even though it was short lived but yet you made to the MVP :). Regardless you will always be a true MVP here at SFSE!

Comment: Congratulations mate :)

Comment: Enjoy your shiny new ♦! You certainly deserve it, and I know you'll do well.

Comment: congratz David !

Comment: Congrats David , very well deserved!

Comment: Congratulations!!

Comment: Congrats David, it's a double header - SFSE Moderator + MVP! Good luck and let's keep pushing SFSE upwards & onwards - Godspeed!

Comment: I expect to see some references to classical Greek in guiding new members :-)

Comment: @cropredy Ναὶ ἔγωγε! χαλεπὰ γὰρ τὰ καλά.

Comment: Congrats @DavidReed!

Comment: Congrats :D @da