# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion

I've been a moderator at Salesforce Stack Exchange for more than four years now. It's been a really lovely time, and I remain incredibly honored by the community's decision to [elect me](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/2019-community-moderator-election-results) as one of its representatives.

I've decided it's time for me to move on, and offer up the diamond to someone else who'd like to bring their energy, passion, and ideas to stewarding and supporting this community. I've notified Stack Exchange and my fantastic co-moderators Adrian and Matt of my intent to step down. I expect that a new moderator election will be held in the near future.

Thank you, again, from the bottom of my heart, for your trust.

(And I won't be gone - I'll keep an eye on questions about packaging, CumulusCI, delivery automation, and the other topics that are near and dear to me).

Comment: David - you were great!   Glad to have met you in person at DF 22!

Comment: Thank you David for all of the time you've invested.  SFSE is an important community resource and an indispensable part of my workflow, and it would not be possible without our mods.

Comment: We appreciate all you've done!

Comment: Thank you for all that you've done for the community, David!

Comment: Moderator or not, you do a fantastic job in answering here at the SFSE. Keep up the good work. Thank you.

Comment: I've always been amazed at how much time you devoted to SFSE along with your activities (including in the NPSP community).  Thanks for all your great work!

Comment: Out of interest, why did you decide to step down?

Comment: Thank you for all your contributions, David!

Comment: Apologies for being late to this - I rarely visit meta. Like everyone else, I thank you for your time as a moderator, but also as a community user and answer giver. I'm glad you'll still be around for that!

Comment: Thank you for all the time put into moderating this community, David! For the rest of the community: the Community Management Team is working with the rest of the moderation team to get an election set up at some point in early 2024 to find a replacement for David.

Answer (score 3):

David, thank you for all the effort you've put in over the last four years! Time sure does fly these days doesn't it?

Apologies for the delay, I don't visit meta as often as I should but these days I seem to have very little free time so most of my time on the site is dealing with flags and then getting back to work!

Your help has been very much appreciated, and glad you'll still be around too :)